# Unable to get espresso dependencies in old eclipse migrated project to android studio.

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

Q . I have an old eclipse build project now migrated to android studio , trying to build an Espresso testcase. Added all the setup dependencies as described in espresso getting started kit .

Not showing dependencies in External libraries in project.[image]

https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

Still i am unable to add espresso imports in my class.

build.gradle  :

```
dependencies 
{
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
    }
}
```

Imports :

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

import android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions;
```

Unable to import the [image: android.support.test. .... .]

its a Eclipse migrated project so didn't have src/androidTest folder, so manually created androidTest/java/Test.java . still not able to see it in external libraries or in imports.

Comment: hi doy you still face the problem

Answer (score 1):

Is your BuildType set to debug? If it's set to anything other than debug it won't be detected.

You set it by clicking on Build Variants tab to the on the left hand side of Android Studio (see images for reference)

[image: Build variants tab]

[image: Set your build variant to debug]